# Why custom properties for IdentityUser custom class are always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a UserManager for my custom Identity user:

```
private readonly UserManager<CustomUser> _userManager;
```

Which has a collection of `Subscriptions`,

```
public class CustomUser:IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

But when I retrieve the user using `userManager`:

```
  var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.UserName);
```

`Subscriptions` is null.

I am adding subscriptions and updating using:

```
 await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

When I check in database for `Subscriptions`, I could see the entries.

But user manager's `Subscriptions` is always returns null.

Comment: Do you insert the entry somewhere? Or are they inserted through the framework? MAybe you have to load the data manually.

Comment: I am adding the user using API , updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserManager.FindAsync.. methods does not include/return navigation properties.

To include navigation proporties we have to use the entityFramework extensions.

In this case use,

```
var userWithSubscriptions =  _userManager.Users.Include(c => c.Subscriptions);
var currentUserSubscription = userWithSubscriptions.Where(x => x.UserName == model.UserName).FirstOrDefault().Subscriptions;
```